# mobi reader for iphone

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

I came to know that iBook does not support mobi files. So I was searched for some mobi reader but could not able to recofnize any top mobi reader. I searched for kindle, Moon readers, etc but unfortunately they are available only in android versions. So Iwould like to knpw if there are any good applications for reading mobi files.

Answer (score 1):

[Kindle App Store link](https://appsto.re/us/Lmrcs.i)

Did you try the official Kindle app? It is a universal app (for iPhone and iPad)

Comment: I just verified it works by downloading and opening a mobi file in the Kindle app.

Comment: I have my account from Nepal, so it showed that kindle was not available for Nepal store

Comment: Oh, I see.  You might want to edit your post to explain your location and the app store you have access to.  Hope you find what you need!